# How to get an official blog for a site?

Tags: support, feature-request, status-declined, blog

How SE sites get [official blogs](http://stackexchange.com/blogs) like [SciFi](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/)?

Even [Islam.se](http://islam.blogoverflow.com/) have it which is still in beta. How can we propose that?

Comment: Well, you have to propose it, I guess, after the community consented that they want one. There is some material about blogs on the main meta that I read recently, but forgot most of it. I planned to ask the community if they want one anyway. You guys are clearly ahead of me each time. ;-) (And of course you need actual users to write it, but I heard *atticae* volunteering recently.)

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/253/could-we-do-a-blog

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Not at all unfortunately!**

As to [this announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244467/162011) the SE framework will not start any new community blogs in the near future, which puts a hold to all blog proposal efforts (for now?).

Answer (score 4):

I'd say we wait until the elections are through and then finally go for it. It does not take much more than defining the scope, contributers and schedule and then bumping it up to the SE guys to set it up for us.

See http://blogoverflow.com/getting-started/:

> 1. Raise the idea on the child meta. A community blog needs the involvement of community members.
> 2. Define the scope and purpose of the blog. Is the blog about the site? Is it about the site’s topic? Is it about the industry around the topic? Keep in mind the audience of your community and their interests. Another generic blog about  may not be all that interesting.
> 3. Recruit contributors. Who will write entries for the blog? Starting a blog is a bit like going through the buffet line. Be realistic – don’t let your eyes be bigger than your stomach. Think seriously about if and how often you will be able to contribute a blog post, including research/prep time.
> 4. Plan a schedule. Given the results of steps #2 and #3, think about a rough idea of a schedule for the blog. Will there be one post a week, posted Mondays? Will there be  posts on Tuesdays and  posts on Fridays? You don’t need to be pushing out posts daily, but I would say at least one post a week.

Comment: I think we probably should follow up on this after the elections are done. I'd love to contribute to this.